# Custom 'Empty' Objects and Settings

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Can I make my own 'empty'-type object in Blender?  Something with its own wireframe 3d model which you can't open in edit mode, for example like a speaker or a light.

Also, is there a way I can give this its own set of settings, unique to those such 'empty' objects? Just how only speakers have settings for volume and pitch, and a light for color and intensity.

Comment: Short answer: no.  Blender's python interface doesn't allow changing the geometry of empties.

Comment: @MartyFouts What about a way of getting extra UI settings, but only on specific objects?

Comment: The scripting language isn't really set up to do that.